Regex match a character a maximum of one time in entire string
I'm looking at URLs and am trying to verify that the ? and # characters are not repeated more than once across the entire string. Browsers will still render the URL, but it's poorly interpreted by back end code that's looking at it, right?
How can I accomplish limiting to a single instance of a specific character (two of them) in the entire string?
https://example.com/go?somewhere=there?this=isbad#anchor1#anchor2
Two ?s, two #s

You can check for ([?#]).*?\1 this will capture any occurance of [?#] to the first group and check if the captured character (referenced with \1)  occurs again later in the string.

Just to mention, doing the same without capture-group and negation between would certainly be more efficient: \?[^?]*\?|#[^#]*#

The string "##" satisfies the requirement, "'?' and '#' characters are not repeated more than once", as "#" is repeated only once. That does not appear to be what you want. It seems that "'?' and '#' characters are not repeated" or "'?' and '#' characters each appear at most once".
